# Interaction handler for Discord.js buttons v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been following guides for the past few days and saw this code for commands. Is there a way to make this for buttons to?

```
if (interaction.isCommand()) {
        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (!command) return interaction.followUp({ content: "This command no longer exists." }) && client.commands.delete(interaction.commandName);

        const arguments = [];

        for (let option of interaction.options.data) {
            if (option.type === 'SUB_COMMAND') {
                option.options?.forEach((x) => {
                    if (x.value) arguments.push(option.value);
                });
            } else if (option.value) arguments.push(option.value);
        };

        command.execute(client, interaction, arguments);
    }
```